# How do I make a list of nearby places in a static location, not current location?

Tags: android

I'm not sure if this has been answered. This feels like such a basic question but I've been looking for a way to do this and all the examples I came across showed a list of places near the device. What I'm trying to do is to specify a location via button click, then show the places near it.

Specifically, if the user clicks button 1, this means the user wants to see the places near train station A, probably in another activity with a RecyclerView.

I was using http://www.zoftino.com/current-location-and-nearby-places-android-example for reference. I followed it all the way to adding the API key in the manifest file but I got stuck trying to analyze how I'm supposed to define a specific location instead of getting the device's location.

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly but so far, I've made a Java bean that can get which station was selected...

```
public class Station {
    String station;

    public Station (String station) {
        this.station = station;
    }
    public Station () {

    }

    public String getStation() {
        return station;
    }

    public void setStation(String station) {
        this.station = station;
    }
```

I also have an activity with an onClick method to check which button was clicked...

```
public void onClick (View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.img1: station = getString(R.string.StationName1);
            Log.d("project", "selected station is " + station);
            break;
        //other cases deleted to make this more concise
    }
    Station selected = new Station (station);
    Log.d("project", "content of station bean is " + selected.getStation());
}
```

I'm testing this using a phone running Android 7.1.1. From the logcat, I know that the Station bean is able to get the selected station correctly. I honestly don't know why I decided to use getString(R.string.StationName1) but considering I'm doing this for 4 train lines and I'm already past the project's deadline. I'd rather not have to change them, if possible.

I was thinking of adding some sort of "coordinates" attribute to the Java bean and passing the exact coordinates using the switch case above but even if I did that, I still wouldn't know how to use it so I can show the nearby locations.

Edit: I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The linked tutorial has the following code block where places are being detected and displayed:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getCurrentPlaceData() {
        Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> placeResult = placeDetectionClient.
                getCurrentPlace(null);
        placeResult.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "current location places info");
                List<Place> placesList = new ArrayList<Place>();
                PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse likelyPlaces = task.getResult();
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    placesList.add(placeLikelihood.getPlace().freeze());
                }
                likelyPlaces.release();

                PlacesRecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new
                        PlacesRecyclerViewAdapter(placesList,
                        CurrentLocationNearByPlacesActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here, the `getCurrentPlace` method uses the current device location, which is the likely cause of your issue. In fact, the Place Detection Client [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceDetectionClient) itself notes that: (emphasis mine)

> The Place Detection API provides quick access to the **device's current place**, and offers the opportunity to report the location of the device at a particular place (like a check in).

Like you said, there doesn't seem to be any API in the Android Places SDK that offers a 'Nearby Places' functionality for a location. Even the above is attempting to associate the current user location with a known place (as opposed to a set of coordinates with no extra info), and doesn't seem to be meant to search for nearby places by design (though it can clearly be done).

However, the Place Search API can be used for your requirements (I have used it in an app that does something similar to what you are looking to do). It includes an endpoint for [Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests), where a static location can be passed. The only downside is that you will have to handle the HTTP calls through Retrofit or something similar, since the SDK doesn't have an existing framework for this API.

Comment: It looks like I bit off more than I can chew.

So to be clear, I can define the API key, location, and radius then use Nearby Search requests to return the nearby places, right?

I have absolutely no idea how to use Retrofit though.